# what is an equivalent of matlab permute(A, [3 2 1]) in python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave

If `A` is a 2x2 array, what is an equivalent expression in python for `permute(A, [3 2 1])` in MATLAB?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming `A` is a `numpy` array of `shape` `(2,2)`

Comment: This question would be MUCH improved if you provided sample input and output.  e.g. `A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.  I would like to get `B = ...`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```
np.transpose( np.expand_dims(A, axis=2), (2, 1, 0) )
```

Since `numpy` does not have trailing Singleton dimensions by default, you need to explicitly add it using [`np.expand_dims`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Or else a shorthand for `np.expand_dims(A, axis=2)` is `A[:, :, None]` so

```
np.transpose(A[:, :, None], (2,1,0))
```

Comment: The above statement gives an error message as A is 2x2 array.  Say, A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).

Comment: Then, np.transpose(a,(2,1,0)) gives the following error message: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c92b9f20f522> in <module>()
----> 1 np.transpose(a,(2,1,0))

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in transpose(a, axes)
    535     except AttributeError:
    536         return _wrapit(a, 'transpose', axes)
--> 537     return transpose(axes)

ValueError: axes don't match array

Comment: In matlab, the above command results 1x2x2 matrix with a[:,:,1] = 1 2, a[:,:,2] = 3 4. How could I achieve the same result in python?

Comment: Yes, you are right! That lack of dimension was giving me a problem, and I am glad to know the way now.

Comment: Nice!  I was wondering how you would do this in `numpy`.  Thanks Shai!